# Merging two mysql queries from different databases in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to merge a pair of MySQL queries from two databases each located on different servers into a single multidimensional associative array. Below is an example of the data I'm working.

The issue seems to be related to the resulting $data0 array values lacking a unique key (ideally the corresponding 'sku' value) to serve as an index for merging the data.

The desired output would be:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [SKU] => 101
        [Description] => Test Item 1
        [On Hand 1] => 3
        [On Hand 2] => 7
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [SKU] => 102
        [Description] => Test Item 2
        [On Hand 1] => 11
        [On Hand 2] => 15
    )
)
```

There may be a better way to handle the MySQL queries and desired array. If so, please let me know. Please provide any feedback as I'm a rank beginner and will take all the help I can get. Thanks!

```
<?
$query1 = "SELECT sku, description, on_hand as 'On Hand 1' FROM database1"

$queryresult1 = mysql_query($query1, $connection1);

$data1 = array();
while ($resultrow1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult1)) {
    array_push($data1, $resultrow1);
}

$query2 = "SELECT sku, on_hand as 'On Hand 2' FROM database2"

$queryresult2 = mysql_query($query2, $connection2);

$data2 = array();
while ($resultrow2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult2)) {
    array_push($data2, $resultrow2);
}

$data0 = array_merge($data1, $data2);

//example code for troubleshooting
$data1 = array('101' => array('SKU' => '101', 'Description' => 'Test Item 1', 'On Hand 1' => 3), '102' => array('SKU' => '102', 'Description' => 'Test Item 2', 'On Hand 1' => 11));
print_r($data1);
echo "<br /><br />";
$data2 = array('101' => array('SKU' => '101', 'On Hand 2' => 7), '102' => array('SKU' => '102', 'On Hand 2' => 15));
print_r($data2);
echo "<br /><br />";
$data0 = array_merge($data1, $data2);

print_r($data0);
?>
```

Comment: different databases or different tables?

Comment: this looks a lot like two tables not databases

Comment: You're just going to have to do two separate queries, save both results to an array and then push those arrays into another array. I think you already have the right idea, and I can't really think of a better way to do it. You can't merge the queries since they're separate databases. Is the method you seem to already be using not working?

Comment: @ShaneLessard The method extracts the database data as needed. The issue seems to be the merging of the data into an array. the array_merge() function seems to append the data in the second array onto the data in the first array when handling multidimensional arrays. Thanks!

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Yeah definitely look into PDO. It'll take you like an hour to get used to (that's how long it took me and I'm quite slow on the uptake). As far as a method to merge the arrays, why not create a new array and use array_push() to push each array to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looping trough each key in `$data1`, you can retreive the value from `$data2` by using the current `$key`. This will give you the result you want:

```
$data1 = array('101' => array('SKU' => '101', 'Description' => 'Test Item 1', 'On Hand 1' => 3), '102' => array('SKU' => '102', 'Description' => 'Test Item 2', 'On Hand 1' => 11));
$data2 = array('101' => array('SKU' => '101', 'On Hand 2' => 7), '102' => array('SKU' => '102', 'On Hand 2' => 15));

$data0 = array();
foreach($data1 as $key => $data){
    $data['On Hand 2'] = $data2[$key]['On Hand 2'];
    $data0[] = $data;
}
unset($data1, $data2);

print_r($data0);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out on this problem. The solution works well! Thanks again! ... Fin for the Win!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// connection 1
$connection1= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
//selecting database 1
mysql_select_db("database1",$connection1);
// select query from the database1 and table 1
$query1 = "SELECT sku, description, on_hand as 'On Hand 1' FROM database1.table1";
$queryresult1 = mysql_query($query1, $connection1);

$data1 = array();
while ($resultrow1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult1)) {
    array_push($data1, $resultrow1);
}
//connection 1
$connection2= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
//selecting database 2
mysql_select_db("database2",$connection2);
// select query from the database2 and table 2
$query2 = "SELECT sku, on_hand as 'On Hand 2' FROM database2.table2";

$queryresult2 = mysql_query($query2, $connection2);

$data2 = array();
while ($resultrow2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult2)) {
    array_push($data2, $resultrow2);
}

$data0 = array_merge($data1, $data2);

print_r($data0);
?>
```

Comment: This seems to append the results of query2 onto the results of query1. The goal is to merge the results, indexed by sku, into a single arrary with keys SKU, On Description, On Hand 1, and On Hand 2. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You'd probably be better off using a single `UNION` query for this:

```
SELECT sku, description, on_hand as 'On Hand 1' FROM database1
UNION ALL
SELECT sku, null       , on_hand as 'On Hand 2' FROM database2
```

Note the use of `null` for the description field in the `database2` query. UNION member queries must have the same number of columns, and the same types.

Then it's a simple matter of:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

without needing two queries, two fetch loops, and a later merge.

Comment: Thanks @marc-b. I'm not sure if the UNION sql function will work as the two databases I'm querying are located on different servers.

Comment: oh, in that case, yeah... you'd need two queries, unless they're both mysql servers and you can set up a federated table.

Answer (score -2):

You can do that by joining the two tables in your query using the `JOIN` syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

So then your query would look like this:

```
SELECT
    table1.sku,
    table1.description,
    table1.on_hand as 'On Hand 1',
    table2.on_hand as 'On Hand 2'
FROM
    database1.table1 JOIN
    database2.table2 ON table1.sku = table2.sku
```

The rows from the two tables will be joined to each other where the sku field value corresponds with each other. You can make a `LEFT JOIN` if you want all the results from table1 and from table2 where possible.

Comment: The JOIN sql function isn't an option as the tables are located on different hosts. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's right, so i lookt a bit further. You can FEDERATE table2 from the second server on the first server: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html Then you can JOIN the two.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have read-only access to these databases as the software provider won't provide write access to minimize their support exposure. I think I'm limited to parsing the two arrays in PHP. Thanks!